# What is the Linux process kernel stack state at process creation?

Tags: linux, x86, stack, kernel, state

I can't find this information anywhere. Everywhere I look, I find things referring to how the stack looks once you hit "main" (whatever your entry point is), which would be the program arguments, and environment, but what I'm looking for is how the system sets up the stack to cooperate with the switch_to macro. The first time the task gets switched to, it would need to have EFLAGS, EBP, the registers that GCC saves, and the return address from the schedule() function on the stack pointed to by "tsk->thread->esp", but what I can't figure out is how the kernel sets up this stack, since it lets GCC save the general purpose registers (using the output parameters for inline assembly).

I am referring to x86 PCs only. I am researching the Linux scheduler/process system for my own small kernel I am (attempting) to write, and I can't get my head around what I'm missing. I know I'm missing something since the fact that Slackware is running on my computer is a testament to the fact that the scheduler works :P

EDIT: I seem to have worded this badly. I am looking for information on how the tasks **kernel** stack is setup not how the tasks **user** task is setup. More specifically, the stack which tsk->thread->esp points to, and that "switch_to" switches to.

Comment: It looks like you have two separate questions here - 1) stack state on process init and 2) kernel `schedule()` in an IRQ. You should probably post one of these questions as a new question and keep one of them here; that way you'll get focused answers on each question. On Stack Overflow, starting a separate question for each question is perfectly fine.

Comment: Alright, will do! I have read answers/questions here for a long time, but never posted! Thanks for the tip :)

Well, I will in about 5 minutes. I have to wait :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The initial kernel stack for a new process is set in `copy_thread()`, which is an arch-specific function.  The x86 version, for example, starts out like this:

```
int copy_thread(unsigned long clone_flags, unsigned long sp,
unsigned long unused,
struct task_struct *p, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    struct pt_regs *childregs;
    struct task_struct *tsk;
    int err;

    childregs = task_pt_regs(p);
    *childregs = *regs;
    childregs->ax = 0;
    childregs->sp = sp;

    p->thread.sp = (unsigned long) childregs;
    p->thread.sp0 = (unsigned long) (childregs+1);

    p->thread.ip = (unsigned long) ret_from_fork;
```

`p->thread.sp` and `p->thread.ip` are the new thread's kernel stack pointer and instruction pointer respectively.

Note that it does *not* place a saved `%eflags`, `%ebp` etc there, because when a newly-created thread of execution is first switched to, it starts out executing at `ret_from_fork` (this is where `__switch_to()` returns to for a new thread), which means that it *doesn't* execute the second-half of the `switch_to()` routine.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! I would never have guessed to look in copy_thread.

Comment: @Caleb1994: It makes sense when you remember that all new threads of execution are created on Linux by cloning an existing one.  I've added another paragraph at the end which might be helpful.

Comment: That did help a lot! My little kernel now supports fork() and a yield() type call :) Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The state of the stack at process creation is described in the [X86-64 SVR4 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) supplement (for AMD64, ie x86-64 64 bits machines). The equivalent for 32 bits Intel processor is probably [ABI i386](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf). I strongly recommend reading also [Assembly HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/). And of course, you should perhaps read the relevant Linux kernel file.

Comment: Those pages describe the state of the stack **after** execution has begun. My problem is the state of the stack **before** execution. i.e. when the kernel is setting up the stack. My only problem is the fact that Linux leaves the compiler to save the general purpose registers (which get saved on the stack), but the way these are saved could be different depending on the compiler, therefore I'm confused on how the system sets up the initial stack. I have looked through the code, but I can't find where the process gets filled. It's hidden behind machine abstraction somewhere.

Comment: The stack does not exist before execution. So I don't understand what you want. The kernel is constructing the initial process stack as described in the ABI documentation.

Comment: Maybe you forgot that kernel & user-space stacks are different?

Comment: Yes. I was mixing them up. Sorry, I meant the kernel stack. The one that the "switch_to" macro switches to (tsk->thread->esp). I assume since state information is saved there, that it's a kernel stack :P I will fix my question accordingly. +1 since technically that did answer the question that I seemed to be asking :P

Answer (score 2):

Google for "linux stack layout process startup" gives [this](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html) link: "Startup state of a Linux/i386 ELF binary", which describes the set up that the kernel performs just before transferring control to the libc startup code.

Comment: is it the state just after `exec`?

Comment: Yes, it's the state just before the first instruction of your process begins to execute.